# How to link social app's avatar with django user model using django-allauth

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I have created Facebook and Twitter authentication with django-allauth. It is working fine as for authentication and I know how to extract logged in user's avatar with this code.

```
'user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url '
```

However, what I want to do is extract all user's avatar from User model but above code only gives me one user's avatar.

I guess I have to link user's avatar with django's User model or store it somewhere.
Could anyone teach me how to do that?

Ref:
http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html